# How to write a scrollable MFC custom control?

Tags: c++, mfc, widget

I want to write my own chart control which requires scrolling.
I found that there is a CScrollView but nothing like this for a control.

Other toolkits like Cocoa, QT or GTK offer me a base class where i can set a content view which is displayed in a viewport and saves me from writting all of the scrolling code.

Comment: MFC was pretty cool for 1995 ...

Comment: I know it is pretty bad, but it is still the official native C++ toolkit and QT is not an alternative to MFC 2008 Feature Pack.

Answer (score -1):

The code for custom scrolling isn't that much. Create the scrollbars, write the message handlers and remember one rectangle for the current visible part.

I would just try it. If you have problems, we are here to help :-)